# PHP gettext issue: strings are only translated for English

Tags: php

I'm using the php gettext implementation to get a website localized according to the user preferences (by analyzing the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE).

I tested the translation system I built and it works correctly, but I just discovered (after I've added other languages) that when I try to use a different language it doesn't work, returning the untranslated string.

I get the right locale (debugging with German settings I get it's using de_DE), and I've the right .mo file (locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo).

I'm using this code to set up the translation environment:

```
    putenv("LC_ALL=" . $g_locale);
    setlocale(LC_ALL,  $g_locale);
    bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');
    bindtextdomain('messages', './locale'); // echo here makes sure it's getting the right absolute path
    textdomain('messages');
```

Where $g_locale is "de_DE".

I tried following several solutions, I've installed the german locale and locale -a is telling de_DE.UTF-8 has been correctly installed. I've also restarted apache2.

But messages are still not translated for any language except en_US.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?
What can I do to make it work?

Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to say it's also working with the default system language (Italian).
It seems like a misconfiguration but I ran the right commands (sudo apt-get install language-pack-de-base).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by simply adding ".UTF-8" to the value of $g_locale resulting in "de_DE.UTF-8" in the case of a German user, "en_US.UTF-8" for English and so on.

After installing all locales I needed each time to restart the webserver (it seems like a caching matters).

On Ubuntu I do not need to use neither `putenv("LC_ALL=" . $g_locale);` nor `bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8');` reducing the amount of code to:

```
// $g_locale = "en_US.UTF-8";
setlocale(LC_ALL,  $g_locale);
bindtextdomain('messages', './locale');
textdomain('messages');
```

Hope this helps, greetings.